# After Compiling sales.jrxml file it create null.jasper instead of sales.jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using the following code to print a report:

```
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;

    try {
        JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("C:\\Nevro\\reports\\salesDetails.jrxml");
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("C:\\Nevro\\reports\\salesDetails.jasper", new HashMap(),
                new JRTableModelDataSource(itemTable.getModel()));
        JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
        jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Invoice.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

In the location `C:\Nevro\reports\` I have created `salesDetails.jrxml`. Then in Java code I read the file and compile it. I expected to create compiled file as `salesDetails.jasper`  but it create only `null.jasper`.

Can any one give me a reason and solution to sort this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename is generated by this line of code within the Jasper library:

```
File destFile = new File(sourceFile.getParent(), jasperDesign.getName() + ".jasper");
```

It takes the path of the `jrxml` file and generates the output file based on the name of your report (configured in the XML).  In your case the report has no name, so you get `null.jasper`.

Comment: job done. Thanks mate your answer guide me to the solution.    my new code is as follow




JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("C:\\Nevro\\reports\\salesDetails.jrxml","C:\\Nevro\\reports\\salesDetails.jasper");

Answer (score 1):

You can also give name of .jasper file explicitly like,

```
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(
                our_jasper_template.jrxml",//the path to the jrxml file to compile
                our_compiled_template.jasper");//the path and name we want to save the com
```

So the above code will generate .jasper file at same location where .jrxml file exists.